# Can i share bridged adapter on windows using ics?

Tags: windows, networking, routing, ics

I would like to bridge two host only networks from vm and then share them as a bridge to some other machines.

I see "Sharing tab" (on windows Control Panel -> Sharing Center -> Network and Internet then right click on network adapter -> Properties and second tab should be sharing) when i want to share them separately, but i can't see this tab when i want to share them at the same time (as a bridge).

Comment: Host-only binds the VM to its host alone. So if you need connectivity between machines, use NAT or Bridged networking.

Comment: Host only is just an example, the thing is i would like to share some networks that are only available on one computer to another using ics. It all works well when i want to share 1 network but when i want to share multiple networks (connected to one bridge) i can't do it becasue i dont see "sharing tab"

Comment: If your machines are on different devices, you need Bridged networking to give them addresses on the main network. Then you should be able to share (standard network connection methods to be used).

Comment: Bridging them together and setting ip works well, only problem is that i dont see "Sharing tab" on bridge adapter so how i can share them using ics?

Comment: Here is a decent article on ICS.  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking-winpc/internet-connection-sharing-in-windows-10/f6dcac4b-5203-4c98-8cf2-dcac86d98fb9    .   If the networks are separated by location, you will likely need a VPN connection between them to use ICS.